# CH-37 Mojave Helicopter decibels

Tags: military, helicopter

What was the decibels level for the Sikorsky CH-37 Mojave Helicopter?   1956 --1959. I need this information for the VA, to process my hearing claim. I was a crew chief in the Army.

Comment: Sounds levels change with distance, what was your proximity?

Comment: Quite a few former crew members [here](http://www.aviastar.org/helicopters_eng/sik_s-56.php) experience the similar hearing problems and same treatment by VA.

Answer (score 4):

Although that specific information may be impossible to get without starting up a Mojave and standing underneath with a sound level meter, it is generally understood that helicopter noise can easily exceed 100db. The CDC indicates that permanent hearing loss can occur after 15 minutes of exposure to this level of sound.

Here is a [link](http://www.mfkv.kg.ac.rs/urbanoise/media/1210_Nis__Tatic_249-253.pdf) to a study on helicopter decibel levels.

Here is a [link](https://www.cdc.gov/nceh/hearing_loss/what_noises_cause_hearing_loss.html) to the CDC page on hearing loss.

Here is a [link](https://www.chem.purdue.edu/chemsafety/Training/PPETrain/dblevels.htm) to a Purdue University chart, listing a Bell helicopter’s sound level at 100db flying 100 feet overhead.

I hope this helps at the VA. Thank you for your service.

Comment: While this is a good answer, links rot, so it is customary to quote the relevant portions of a linked document in the answer itself.

Comment: Noise level of one installation can only be used make rough estimates for noise levels on other installations. Decibel is a very tricky unit, and keeping in mind the complexity of acoustics, I would not use engine noise in this aircraft to present the noise level of the same engine type on that aircraft.

Comment: Direct quotes are not necessary as the only relevant data - 100db sound level and its negative effect on hearing - has been included.

Comment: Engine noise is only one component of noise when it comes to helicopters. Engines, main rotors and anti-torque systems each add to the total sound level in separate Hz ranges.